# Text encoding error when opening Notification Center plist using stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:

Tags: objective-c, string, macos, cocoa

I want to write a function that finds out whether "Do Not Disturb" is turned on, on a Mac.

So I have written this function:

```
-(BOOL)dndIsOn{
    NSString* path =  [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.notificationcenterui.%@.plist",[self getSystemUUID]] stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *txtFileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    NSLog(@"string:%@ error:%@",txtFileContents,error);
    if ([txtFileContents rangeOfString:@"<fals"].location == NSNotFound) {
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

But the `txtFileContents` string error returns:

> .... .plist” couldn’t be opened using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8)."

Why is this happening?

Comment: Why do you read the .plist as a text file? `return [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path][@"doNotDisturb"]] boolValue];`?

Comment: brilliant! Works a treat. Still confused with the text error though!?

Comment: I don't know. I opened mine with a text editor, and the first line states: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>". But since it's a Plist, you miss all the parsing if you read it as a simple text file.

Comment: Alternative on the cmd line `defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.notificationcenterui.* doNotDisturb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read a .plist which top level is a dictionary using `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:`. In case the top level is a array, you have to use `arrayWithContentsOfURL:`. This will automatically parse the file.

In your case, the top level is a dictionary.
The key is `doNotDisturb`.

The value you want to return:

```
BOOL doNotDisturbSet = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path][@"doNotDisturb"]] boolValue];
```